# Incompatible shapes error in bayesian neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, bayesian-networks, edward

I am a new in machine learning. I have a project about bayesian neural network to predict football result. Then I follow instruction from [this link](https://www.kaggle.com/itoeiji/bayesian-neural-network-with-edward). Then I make code like this:

```python
import sys
from math import floor

import edward as ed
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from edward.models import Normal, Categorical
from fancyimpute import KNN
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data = pd.read_csv('features_dummies_with_label.csv', sep=',')


def impute_missing_values_by_KNN():
    home_data = data[[col for col in data.columns if 'hp' in col]]
    away_data = data[[col for col in data.columns if 'ap' in col]]
    label_data = data[[col for col in data.columns if 'label' in col]]

    home_filled = pd.DataFrame(KNN(3).complete(home_data))
    home_filled.columns = home_data.columns
    home_filled.index = home_data.index

    away_filled = pd.DataFrame(KNN(3).complete(away_data))
    away_filled.columns = away_data.columns
    away_filled.index = away_data.index

    data_frame_out = pd.concat([home_filled, away_filled, label_data], axis=1)

    return data_frame_out


dataset = impute_missing_values_by_KNN()

dataset = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)

data_x = dataset.loc[:, dataset.columns != 'label'].as_matrix().astype(np.float32)
data_y_ = dataset.loc[:, 'label'].as_matrix().astype(np.float32)

enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded = np.array(data_y_).reshape(-1)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
onehot_encoded = enc.fit_transform(integer_encoded)

data_y = onehot_encoded

train_size = 0.9

train_cnt = floor(data_x.shape[0] * train_size)

N = int(train_cnt)

train_x, test_x = data_x[0:N], data_x[N:]
train_y, test_y = data_y[0:N], data_y[N:]

in_size = train_x.shape[1]
out_size = train_y.shape[1]

EPOCH_SUM = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 10

train_y2 = np.argmax(train_y, axis=1)
test_y2 = np.argmax(test_y, axis=1)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500

x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, in_size])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# def neural_network_model(data):
w_h1 = Normal(loc=tf.zeros([in_size, out_size]), scale=tf.ones([in_size, out_size]))

b_h1 = Normal(loc=tf.zeros([out_size]), scale=tf.ones([out_size]))

y_pre = Normal(tf.matmul(x_, w_h1) + b_h1, scale=1.0)

qw_h1 = Normal(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size, out_size])),
               scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size, out_size])))

qb_h1 = Normal(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([out_size])), scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([out_size])))

y = Normal(tf.matmul(x_, qw_h1) + qb_h1, scale=1.0)

inference = ed.KLqp({w_h1: qw_h1, b_h1: qb_h1}, data={y_pre: y_})
inference.initialize()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

with sess:
    samples_num = 100
    for epoch in tqdm(range(EPOCH_SUM), file=sys.stdout):
        perm = np.random.permutation(N)
        for i in range(0, N, BATCH_SIZE):
            batch_x = train_x[perm[i:i + BATCH_SIZE]]
            batch_y = train_y2[perm[i:i + BATCH_SIZE]]
            inference.update(feed_dict={x_: batch_x, y_: batch_y})
        y_samples = y.sample(samples_num).eval(feed_dict={x_: train_x})
        acc = (np.round(y_samples.sum(axis=0) / samples_num) == train_y2).mean()
        y_samples = y.sample(samples_num).eval(feed_dict={x_: test_x})
        tets_acc = (np.round(y_samples.sum(axis=0) / samples_num) == test_y2).mean()
        if (epoch + 1) % 1 == 0:
            tqdm.write('epoch:\t{}\taccuracy:\t{}\tvaridation accuracy:\t{}'.format(epoch + 1, acc, tets_acc))
```

But, when I debug it there is error like this:

```python
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [10] vs. [10,3]
     [[Node: inference/sample/Normal_2/log_prob/standardize/sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_Placeholder_1_0_1, inference/sample/Normal_2/loc)]]
```

in this line:

> inference.update(feed_dict={x_: batch_x, y_: batch_y})

What is the meaning of error? And how to solve it?

Comment: FYI, [tag:edward] has its own tag

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the traceback it is difficult to debug the error. However I assume that the Tensors or Arrays you are passing to inference.update are of another shape as the ones you defined in declaration. I would therefore check the shapes of e.g: batch_x, train_x (for every iteration), w_h1, qw_h1, ... . 
Print those arrays/Tensors out or debug using tfdbg and compare them.

Please consider this answer not as final, but rather as a comment. However due to the fact that I have < 50 points I cannot comment. I wanted however to contribute because I think that my post could contribute to a solution.